# sql query alphabetical initials

Tags: jquery, database, oracle, alphabetical

The question I am struggling to understand is:

> Write a query to list the number of ingredients starting with initial alphabetical character. Your output should have <= 26 rows and ordered alphabetically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 CREATE TABLE Ingredient
 ( 
     idI NUMBER              constraint pk_Ingredient PRIMARY KEY ,
     ingrDesc VARCHAR2(100)  constraint nn1Ingredient not null
 );
CREATE TABLE Recipe
(
    idR NUMBER                constraint pk_recipe PRIMARY KEY ,
    recipeTitle VARCHAR2(200)  constraint nn1Recipe not null,
    prep Text VARCHAR2(4000),
    cuisineType VARCHAR2(50),
    mealType VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ch_mealType CHECK (mealType IN ('starter', 'main', 'dessert', null))
);
CREATE TABLE RecpIngr
(
    idR NUMBER ,
    hidI NUMBER ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_RecpIngr PRIMARY KEY (idR, idI),
    CONSTRAINT fk1RecpIngr_recipe foreign key(idR) references Recipe,
    CONSTRAINT fk2RecpIngr_ingredient foreign key(idI) references Ingredient
)
organization index;
```

Comment: You have to give us a course credit for helping with your home work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if i got your table realation right 
but this is more or less what you need (many ways can give you the same solutions) :

```
 select * from 
(
select distinct a.ingrDesc , b.recipeTitle 
from  Ingredient a,
    Recipe b
    RecpIngr c
where b.idR = b.idR 
and a.idI = c.idR
)
where rownum <= 26
 Order by ingrDesc
```

Comment: This solution lacks an ORDER BY clause and so cannot guarantee "ordered alphabetically".